# Login View loading with calling Login Action in .net core web application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on a .net core web application. The strange behaviour I am observing is as follows:

1. Initially user goes to the Login page and log in using credentials. At this stage when Login View is displayed (routed technically) GET ACTION METHOD LOGIN is called and the view is displayed. When the user submits the login form POST ACTION METHOD LOGIN is called. Till here all works great.
2. After the user is logged in when the user navigate to the login page in a new tab of the same browser (session is open) by directly going to URL https://url/Controller/Login the Login view is displayed to the user but GET ACTION METHOD LOGIN is not called. I have checked behaviour by applying breakpoints and no action method is called still Login view displays.
3. After which if the user try to login it shows an HTTP 404 error (I think because the user is already logged)
4. Now if I clear cache and then navigate to the login page by https://url/Controller/Login all works fine again.

Maybe I am missing some technicality here anyone observed such behaviour or have an idea what's going on.

Comment: Share your relevant code. This kind of explanation doesn't help to get into the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It has been resolved it was due to the offline feature of AMP was enabled. After disabling it works fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).